# App with Google Maps doesn't build in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to build an app with Google Maps but whenever I try to run it there's an error message. I've added the following code to my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And here's the error message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Fredrik\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\dx.bat --dex --output 
C:\Users\Fredrik\AndroidStudioProjects\Skollunch\app\build\dex\debug 
C:\Users\Fredrik\AndroidStudioProjects\Skollunch\app\build\classes\debug 
C:\Users\Fredrik\AndroidStudioProjects\Skollunch\app\build\dependency-cache\debug 
C:\Users\Fredrik\AndroidStudioProjects\Skollunch\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-0245b39e700edf6a0cb399c720bb8d324f78e6d1.jar 
C:\Users\Fredrik\AndroidStudioProjects\Skollunch\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-05dd9eee723585a17563ec87ce727a6f7bafa3c6.jar 
C:\Users\Fredrik\AndroidStudioProjects\Skollunch\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.0.1-b477505a5fac609297d4a580b1fdd1110916d42b.jar

Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

When I delete the code in build.gradle it runs fine, but then Maps won't work of course ;). This isn't just the case with Play Services but it does the same thing when I try to add the Support Library.

Does anyone know something that could help me solve the problem?

Comment: Some where in your application you are referring to two different version of same thing.Try this : clean your project from `Build > Clean Project` and use `File > Inavalidate Cache/ Restart`

Comment: Do you have any other modules in your project? What jar files are in your libs folder?

Comment: @Rani unfortunately it didn't help...

Comment: @ScottBarta only android-support-v4.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Gradle, don't include android-support-v4 by including the jar file directly; if you do it this way, the build system isn't able to disambiguate multiple copies of the support library it may encounter through direct or transitive dependencies, and you get exactly this error. Instead, remove the jar from your **libs** directory and include it by supplying its Maven coordinate in the `dependencies` block of your build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: You, my friend, just made my night! Thank you much for this! Finally i can continue with my app.